# Intergrade Firebase storage with Mongo Db Atlas

Tags: mongodb, firebase, google-cloud-storage

What is the best way to intergrade Firebase storage with MongoDB atlas? In the perfect world I would like to be able to store my images from Firebase in MongoDB as an instance that I can refer to it by ID. Then I can query it via express route in node, and finally display it on the front end using React.
Is this even possible to create an id in mongo atlas by intergrading the two? Note: I am asking about the storage from firebase, not the Realtime database they offer. I have looked into zipier and that doesn't handle storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THE ANSWER IS SO SIMPLE:

Through Mongo Atlas, create a new collection, then copy and paste URL into the collection! Thank you Lord!